# find same input data and replace it to new one before write it to txt output

Tags: php, replace

i had some trouble with my php code, its look like this

```
<form method="post">
        jumlah cetak?
        <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="'.$file.'">
        <input type="text" name="field2" maxlength="4" size="4">
        <input type="submit" value="SIMPAN">
        </form>

<?php
 $path = '../data.txt';
 if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
 $fh = fopen($path,"a+");
 $string = $_POST['field1'].' | '.$_POST['field2'].''  ;
 $string = $string.PHP_EOL;
 fwrite($fh,$string); // Write information to the file
 fclose($fh); // Close the file
 }
 ?>
```

and result in my "data.txt" when i input some data

```
IMG_7892.jpg | 3
Bilqis.JPG | 7
IMG_7892.jpg | 1
Bilqis.JPG | 8
```

**its shows i've take  2 filename to be processed twice. which :**

(1) IMG_7892.jpg from 3 files and changing it  to be 1 file

(2) Bilqis.JPG from 7 files changing it to be 8 files

what i want is when i input same filename and change the value
its like this "data.txt", (just write last input on txt)

```
   IMG_7892.jpg | 1
   Bilqis.JPG | 8
   ...etc to other filename
```

how to make it like that? please help me?

Comment: the problem lies in the update, you're merely just appending every form submission, you need to search for the one you need to update, then write again

Comment: its just painful to store this data this way, why not just utilize a mysql table

Comment: @Ghost can you help me to show how?. my "B" didnt want to use mysgl

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to guess how the output is being generated, which should be rather simple to append `*from*` and `*to*` in there, yet another option would be to just `preg_replace` afterwards, even though this is not the right way, with an expression similar to:

```
(IMG_.+\s*.*\..+.*\s*)(IMG_.+\s*.*\..+.*)
```

and replace it with:

```
*from*\n$1$2\n\n*to*\n$2
```

and it might work.

#### Test

```
$re = '/(IMG_.+\s*.*\..+.*\s*)(IMG_.+\s*.*\..+.*)/mi';
$str = 'IMG_7892.jpg | 3
Bilqis.JPG | 7
IMG_7892.jpg | 1
Bilqis.JPG | 8';
$subst = '*from*\\n$1$2\\n\\n*to*\\n$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zMrbPd/2/)

```
*from*
IMG_7892.jpg | 3
Bilqis.JPG | 7
IMG_7892.jpg | 1
Bilqis.JPG | 8

*to*
IMG_7892.jpg | 1
Bilqis.JPG | 8
```

Comment: i've try that, but still didnt resolve. but thank you Emma